# Binary Search won't ever finish, I have to terminate it myself

Tags: java, binary-search

```
public static boolean binarySearch(int[] data, int value){
    int start = 0; 
    int end = data.length-1;
    int middle = (start + end) / 2;
        while(end >= start){
            if(data[middle] == value){
                System.out.println("binarySearch found value " + value + " at position " + data[middle]);
                return true;
            }
            if(data[middle] < value){
                start = middle + 1; 
            }
            if(data[middle] > value){
                end = middle + 1; 
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

I have this code for binary search, and to me it looks like everything is in check. But when i pass an array and a variable I'm looking for through it it doesn't give me anything in return and I just have to terminate it. Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems that you would be entering an infinite loop. Have you tried debugging your program to find out why?

Comment: There's a pretty obvious error in your code. Use a debugger and trace through your code and make sure the values of your variables are what you expect them to be at each step. (Actually, two pretty obvious errors.)

Comment: Let's see... which variable is needed for evaluating values that should change in every loop, but is never assigned a value inside the loop?

Comment: Shouldn't you recalculate _middle_ value inside while -loop?

Comment: I am somewhat new to coding and debugging unfortunately isn't something thats taught so I've never really been good at it. Our professor tells us to put system.out.print(".") so we can watch it but I'm not sure where to put that in this code

Comment: @harism yes! thank you thats what it was. Thanks everyone else also

Comment: Just to say few months ago I was writing my own binary search when I realized I could use Collections.binarySearch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(data[middle] == value)
```

this part checks if the middle of the array equals to data **all the time**. If you don't modify the variable `middle`, no matter what you do, it will always check if the middle value is equal to `data`.

Since you don't modify `start` and `end` as well,

```
 while(end >= start)
```

this part also prevents you to finish the loop.

This is what I tried:

```
int data[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12};
int value = 7;
binarySearch(data, value);
```

And this is the output I get when I add

```
 System.out.println("Start: " + start +
 " Middle: " + middle + " End: " + end);
```

at the beginning of `while` loop:

```
Start: 4 Middle: 3 End: 6
Start: 4 Middle: 3 End: 6
Start: 4 Middle: 3 End: 6
Start: 4 Middle: 3 End: 6
Start: 4 Middle: 3 End: 6
Start: 4 Middle: 3 End: 6
Start: 4 Middle: 3 End: 6
...
```

to infinity.